# Detecting & highlighting macroblocks in an image with compression artifacts

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-image

[image: Part of a large image with macroblocks]

Hello,
  I have an image a portion of which has macro-blocking effect. In the attachment below, I have taken a region of this macroblock using scikit & numpy arrays. I am curious to know if there is a way to identify such regions in an image and highlight / quantify them i.e identify only the horizontal & veritical lines/blocks / bounday & highlight them and discard all the curvature (angular) edges that may be part of the larger image.

I have tried using the Hough line transform, and I see colored lines in other angles along with horizontal & veritical lines. I want to supress other angles that are not 0/90 deg. Is this possible with scikit-image apis?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: a) Do you have a full resolution test image and b) did you try to set the angles of the hough transform to 0 and pi/2?

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt Thank you very much for pointing my mistake. I was missing the theta parameter because of which default angles of -np.pi/2 to np.pi/2 were being plotted. After I changed this, I got it working.